# ESXi keeps prompting for password after adding ssh public key to authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, esxi

I want to add my ssh public key to the ESXi 7 host, so that I can login via ssh without using password.

But the esx host keep prompting me for the password.

I have tried the following:

## Scenario A

**When using the "normal" way of adding ssh keys to a host.**

1. Make a ssh key pair with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Push ssh public key to ESXi host with `ssh-copy-id root@esx.host`
3. Now try login to esx host using `ssh root@esx.host`

This will prompt you for a password again.

**Reason for failing**

The ssh key is added to the esx hosts `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` - but the SSH service, expect to find the keys in `/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys`.

## Scenario B

**Adding the the right place**

1. Copy the key into esx by `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@esx.host 'cat >>/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys'`
2. Try login again with `ssh root@esx.host`

Still asking for password.

Comment: This is good info, but is better suited for [su] or [sf]. This is nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

## Scenario B is failing for a reason

**Reason for failing**

The ssh key is generated with by default 2048 bits, but should be 4096 bits.

**Final Solution**

```
# Generate the 4096 ssh key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

# Copy the public key the right place on the esx host
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@esx.host 'cat >>/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys'

# Then login
ssh root@esx.host
```

Tada - now logged in without using password

```
Password:
The time and date of this login have been sent to the system logs.

WARNING:
   All commands run on the ESXi shell are logged and may be included in
   support bundles. Do not provide passwords directly on the command line.
   Most tools can prompt for secrets or accept them from standard input.

VMware offers supported, powerful system administration tools.  Please
see www.vmware.com/go/sysadmintools for details.

The ESXi Shell can be disabled by an administrative user. See the
vSphere Security documentation for more information.
[root@esx.host:~]
```